# Installing R on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, analysis

I am a new user of Ubuntu and facing lot problem in fetching R packages from the nearby CRAN repository. I am using Ubuntu v10.04 and R v2.14.1. I am not able to fetch package like twittR, plyR etc. . Can anyone tell me the appropriate steps for it as I have to use this for performing sentiment analysis on twitter data. is it because of old versions of the softwares??

Comment: Your `R`version 2.14.1 is outdated. The current release is version 3.2.1. Most of the recent packages won't work on the old version of `R` that you are using. Try to install the current version by following the instructions at https://cran.r-project.org/ . Once you have installed the current version of `R`, try again to install the packages.

Comment: By the way, the ubuntu version also seems to be quite old. Why don't you upgrade to the most recent LTS version, which I think is v14.04 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get Ubuntu 14.04. What are you doing with 10.04?

Add the public key for the Ubuntu CRAN release:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Add a nearby CRAN mirror to the deb list by editing the sources.list:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the file, add this line to the end of the file:

```
deb http://watson.nci.nih.gov/cran_mirror/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

This will add the Bethesda NIH R mirror to our ubuntu trusted sources list. Next, we will update apt-get packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install (the updated versions of) Base-R and Dev-R:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

To set up a shared library folder, edit .bash_profile and/or .bashrc to set up

```
R_LIBS_USER='directory_of_your_choice'.
```

Do make sure to set proper read/write permissions for your users. For more help, go the the [AskUbuntu stack exchange](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: FWIW, a more "neutral" repository such as `http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/` may be the better recommendation. (Via [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04).)

Answer (score 1):

Your software installation is *five years old* so you limit yourself to what was available *five years ago*.  For *current* packages, use a *current* R on a *current* OS installation.

I update every six months (usually a month or two after the release) to the then-current Ubuntu version.  Works like a charm.